# Cordova Application Development Guidelines

Tags: cordova, mobile

I'm looking for a bit of advice on developing my first Cordova application.

I Was planning on using just jquery mobile to develop it and it seems relatively straightforward. The more I read into getting started the more I read about different technologies, like Ionic, Angular, handlebars, rachet. I'm wondering if I should be using one of these instead of jquery mobile or using them along with jquery mobile.

I'm also trying to figure out the best data storage message. I would like the application to have some local storage for offline access and be synced to a server and other devices. I want a relational database so I can create a simple CRM system. I'm not sure if I can be doing this with web storage using key/value pairs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Too broad question. Let me answer this according to my knowledge

`Jquery mobile` -> simple to code, works well, a bit slow

`Ionic + angular js` -> native look, and good performence

Most of the people in SO suggest `Ionic + angular js`, will perform better than JQM

**Database**:

There is `WEBSQL` and `SQLite` wrappers. I think these databases will serve you better. WebSql is good, but from my experience till now I'll suggest you to use a SQLite wrapper plugin.

Comment: I agree, I have worked with both, jqm and ionic with angular and the latest make development a lot easier, quite powerful and enforce a more clean architecture. Also the app respond faster than jqm.

Comment: Sorry for the broad question but you answered it well. I need a broader understanding, there's just so much info out there at the moment. I think I'm going to look at you suggestion of Ionic and Angular JS. I need to look into SQLite wrapper. Cheers.